# Is it possible to set USB device priority?

Tags: usb, video, priority

I am using Windows 10 Pro and bought a Fresco Logic 2000 USB to HDMI adapter. It works but when playing videos on the screen attached with USB it makes my mouse and keyboard slow down and be jumpy when playing youtube videos.

It is connected to a USB 3 on my PC and the mouse & keyboard is attached to a USB 2 on the PC.

Can I change the priority so that my mouse and keyboard do not jump or lower the priority of the HDMI adapter?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my laptop when connecting to a display via USB, I solved it through taking the following steps:

1. Open **Device Manager**.
2. Right click the problematic USB device and click 'Properties'.

[image]

3. Navigate to the Power Management tab and uncheck '*Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power*', then press OK.

[image]

Comment: what about the case with two different USB devices transferring data and one of them is monopolizing most of the bandwidth and starving the other?  Can you set a priority so that the other device get priority?